# Complement of a codimension $k\geq 2$ submanifold is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, connectedness, submanifold

It is proved in Theorem 3.44 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* ([http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATplain.pdf](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATplain.pdf)) that if $K$ is a compact, locally contractible subspace of a closed orientable $n$-manifold $M$, then $H_i(M, M -K;\Bbb  Z) = H^{n-i}(K; \Bbb Z)$ for all $i$. In particular, if $M$ is a closed orientable $n$-manifold and $K$ is a compact, codimension $\geq 2$ submanifold of $M$, we can easily see that $H_0(M-K;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z$ using the homology long exact sequence for $(M,M-K)$, which implies that $M-K$ is connected and hence path-connected (since $M-K$ is locally path-connected). But I think the assumptions that $M$ being compact, orientable and $K$ being compact are restrictive, and I'm curious about the following questions:

1. If $M$ is an $n$-manifold and $K$ is a codimension $\geq 2$ submanifold then $M-K$ is path-connected. Is this statement true?
2. If 1 is true, then is the following more general statement true? If $M$ is a complex $n$-manifold and $K$ is a (complex) codimension $\geq 1$ analytic subvariety, then $M-K$ is path-connected.

Comment: I guess it is not clear whether you want a proof or just to know the answer. Both 1 and 2 are true (assuming M is path connected).

Comment: @NickL Thanks. Is there a reference for proofs of 1 and 2?